# Mapping $f: N → Z$ which is injective but not surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find description for mapping:
$$f: N → Z$$ 
which is injective but not surjective and has atleast 199 elements from range values with pattern in domain.

N ... natural numbers

Z ... integers

Hope you can understand my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern"?

Answer (score 3):

How about just mapping n, a positive integer, into **itself**?